# Override the Getter of a String

Tags: javascript, string, object, getter-setter

This is just a proof of concept.

In JavaScript a `"string"` is an Object of type `String`

If I have a special string like an Apple, which by default should behave like a String:

Expected behavior:

`var myFruit = new Apple('macintosh')`

the value of `myFruit` should be `"apple - macintosh"`

when I create an array:

```
var myApple = new Apple('macintosh');
var myBanana = new Banana('chiquita');
var myFruits = [ myApple, myBanana ]

// ["apple - macintosh", "banana - chiquita"]
```

but as this Strings are of special types, it would be cool, if I could do something like this:

`myApple.setType("gala")`

and the value of `myApple` && `myFruits[0]` would be `"apple - gala"`

My assumption was to work with **defineGetter**, but it only works with normal Objects `{}` because you have to define the explicit getter of the `object`.

This is from the `Object` reference at Mozilla:

> ```
> // Non-standard and deprecated way
>
> var o = {};
> o.__defineGetter__('gimmeFive', function() { return 5; });
> console.log(o.gimmeFive); // 5
>
>
> // Standard-compliant ways
>
> // Using the get operator
> var o = { get gimmeFive() { return 5; } };
> console.log(o.gimmeFive); // 5
>
> // Using Object.defineProperty
> var o = {}; 
>
> Object.defineProperty(o, 'gimmeFive', {
>   get: function() {
>     return 5;   
>   }
> });
> console.log(o.gimmeFive); // 5
> ```

So in my scenario the `getter` would be the `String object` itself, so is it possible at all?

#### What I have tried

Using `valueOf` and `toString`

```
var Fruit = function(fruit, type) {
  this.fruit = fruit;
  this.type = type;
}

Fruit.prototype.toString = Fruit.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.fruit + " - " + this.type
}

function apple(type) {
  return new Fruit('apple', type)
}
var myApple = apple('macintosh')

// NICE
myApple + ""         // apple - macintosh
myApple.toString()   // apple - macintosh

// UUUPS
console.log(myApple)    // => {fruit: "apple", type: "macintosh"}
JSON.stringify(myApple) // => {fruit: "apple", type: "macintosh"}
```

Comment: You may define your custom `toString()` method in objects than it will be used when converting objects to `string`. In JS primitive types including strings are immutable so you can't add properties to them. You can only add properties to primitive wrappers like `new Number(1)` or `new String('foo')`. I don't fully get your question but maybe this will help you...

Comment: @csharpfolk I'll tried it, and I'll update the question in short

Comment: @csharpfolk please check out the edits

Comment: `JSON.stringify` can be fixed by defining `toJSON()` method on your objects. You are wrong when you thinking that `"foo"` is object, `"foo"` is *primitive type* e.g. `typeof("foo")` is `"string"`, `typeof(new String("foo"))` is "object". You cannot define/add/remove any field/method from primitive type. Even if you call `console.log(new String('f'))` in chrome it prints ugly object braces...

Comment: But `JSON.stringify(new String('f'))` is "f"

Comment: Yes, you are right, as a Primitive, you cannot even assign a property to it..